# Invalid left-hand side in assignment error. Can't find the mistake

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying this code in javascript. but it's giving me this error.

```js
var x = 1;

while (x <= 20) {
  var result = (x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 5 = 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : (x % 3 === 0) ? "Fizz" : (x % 5 === 0) ? "Buzz" : x);
console.log(result);
}
```

I thought that it was due to me assigning 'x' which is a number to 'result' which was at some point a string, so I tried to replace the final 'x' with a string, same thing.

**I know I can write this with normal if-else statement but I would like to know how to do it with inline conditionals**

Comment: Your parentheses don't balance.

Comment: Don't try to do nested ternaries. Use normal `if` statements.

Comment: `x % 5 === 5 = 0` is supposed to mean what?

Comment: If you want to know if something is divisible by both 3 and 5, just check if it's divisible by 15.

Comment: `x % 5 === 5 = 0` should be `x % 5 === 0`. That's the reason for the "invalid left hand side" error -- you can't assign to a comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much for all who helped. My parentheses didn't match and also I had a weird `x % 5 === 5 = 0` in the code. Also after solving that it went into an infinite loop because I didn't iterate the counter. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of your code

```
var result = (x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 5 = 0)
```

you have at right `= 0` this means, "Hey You at LEFT" receive this value, but, you have not a
regular variable to assign it at LEFT SIDE, so javascript understand that you want assign `0` to a comparison, `x % 3 === 0 && x % 5 === 5` and we know that it is not possible because this evaluates to a boolean (true or false), you can't express: `true = 0`. This is the reason why this exception was throwed